# "Undefined Reference To 'IMG_Load'" CodeBlocks and SDL_Image Error

Tags: c, sdl, codeblocks, undefined-reference, sdl-image

I'm learning SDL through Lazy Foo's tutorial, but I can't proceed further as IMG_Load doesn't seem to work. I tried setting it up like he says, but it just doesn't work. I put all the include files into include folder, and all the lib files into the lib folder. What I found is that there were x86 and x64 folders in the lib folder. When I tried x64 (because I have a 64-bit system)it all worked fine, CodeBlocks even told me suggestions (like when I wrote "img" it showed up a suggestion "IMG_Load" (which means the library got initalized?)), but when I come to compiling my code, this happens: http://puu.sh/3Eqa5.png. When I try with the x86 version, exact same error.

I had a little search around the internet, and all I could find were a few threads, but most of them were abandoned. The closest I got to answering my problem was this: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/118299-sdl-image-error-sdl/ but the guy solved his problem by downloading a problem which Linux can use, not Windows.
}

I'm running Windows 7 64-bit, CodeBlocks 12.11, SDL 1.2.15 and SDL_Image 1.2.12.

I really don't know what the problem is!

Comment: Add the command Codeblock is using to compile your project to your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I set up additional SDL libraries in CodeBlocks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17684421/how-do-i-set-up-additional-sdl-libraries-in-codeblocks)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the @Aleeee's answer, a command line solution is to add `-lSDL2_image` compiler flag (SDL2 is the up-to-date version by the time of this writing).

Compilation example:

```
gcc -o object_file_name source_file_name.c `sdl2-config --cflags --libs` -lSDL2_image
```

Answer (score 3):

You should go to the Compiler and Debugger settings again and under the Linker Settings tab paste:
-lSDL_image
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the SDL_Image library I was using was buggy. I don't know how that happened though. I just had to use a older version. Thanks to anyone who helped!